# Simplifying/expanding the floor of a product

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there any way of simplifying or expanding the following expression:

$\lfloor ab\rfloor$

where $a$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$? I know there exist formulae that allow simplifying the floor of a sum, or the floor of a quotient of two integers, but none that invlove the floor of a product. If simplifying is not possible, is there a way to expand it so that $a$ and $b$ are not "grouped" together within the floor function? Something like $\lfloor ab\rfloor = \lfloor a\rfloor \lfloor b\rfloor +...$

Comment: I don't think you can simplify that